# Erro ao fazer a soma com javascript

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho um código que gera dinamicamente vários *inputs*. Além disso tenho uma função que deveria somar o valor informado dentro dos *inputs*. O problema é que ao invés de somar ele concatena os campos. O estranho é que fiz o mesmo processo em outro lugar e funciona a soma.

**Código Javascript:**

```
var tam_grade_produto = document.querySelectorAll("#tam_grade_produto");
var quant_produto = document.querySelectorAll("#quant_produto");

var quant_total_produto = document.querySelector("#quant_total_produto").value;

function preencheTotalProduto(){
  var calc_quant_total_produto = 0;
  for(var i=0;i<tam_grade_produto.length;i++){
    calc_quant_total_produto += quant_produto[i].value;
  }
  quant_total_produto.textContent = calc_quant_total_produto;
}

document.addEventListener("onchange",function(event){
    event.preencheTotalProduto();
});

preencheTotalProduto();
```

**O código abaixo está dentro de um** `for` **e gera campos que preciso:**

```
<tr>
    <td><kbd><label id="tam_grade_produto"><?= $tamanho['tamanho']; ?></label></kbd></td>
    <td><input size="3" class="form-control" id="quant_produto" type="number" onchange="preencheTotalProduto()" min="1" max="<?= $tamanho['estoque']; ?>"></td>
    <td><input size="3" readonly="true" class="form-control" type="number" onchange="preencheTotalProduto()" value="<?= $tamanho['estoque']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
```

**E esse é o trecho do código que deveria armazenar a soma:**

```
<div>Total de pares: <label id="quant_total_produto">0</label></div>
```

Mas ao preencher o valor de uns 3 inputs com os valores de 1, 2 e 3, por exemplo, no total de pares não aparece 6 e sim 0123. Parece que está concatenando ao invés de somar. Alguém sabe dizer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu código está um pouco confuso, mas vamos ver um exemplo do porquê uma soma pode não funcionar com JavaScript.

O primeiro ponto que merece destaque é que quando pegamos o `value` com JavaScript ele retornará uma *string*. Para converter para um *integer* e poder somar numericamente esse valores você precisará usar uma função chamada `parseInt()`.

Veja esse exemplo **sem** o `parseInt()`:

```js
function somarValores() {
  let s1 = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
  let s2 = document.getElementById("txt2").value;
  let s3 = document.getElementById("txt3").value;
  let resposta = (s1 + s2 + s3);
  alert(resposta);
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Cálculo de soma sem utilizar o parseInt</legend>
  <p>
    <label>Valor 1:</label>
    <input id="txt1" type="number" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Valor 2: </label>
    <input id="txt2" type="number" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Valor 3: </label>
    <input id="txt3" type="number" />
  </p>
  <button id="somar" onclick="somarValores()">Somar</button>
</fieldset>
```

Ao digitar, por exemplo, 10 no primeiro campo, 10 no segundo e terceiro teremos o valor: 101010. O que aconteceu é que ele concatenou as *strings*, não somou.

Agora veja esse exemplo **com** o `parseInt()`:

```js
function somarValores() {
  let s1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt1").value);
  let s2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt2").value);
  let s3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt3").value);
  let resposta = (s1 + s2 + s3);
  alert(resposta);
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Cálculo de soma utilizando o parseInt</legend>
  <p>
    <label>Valor 1:</label>
    <input id="txt1" type="number" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Valor 2: </label>
    <input id="txt2" type="number" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Valor 3: </label>
    <input id="txt3" type="number" />
  </p>
  <button id="somar" onclick="somarValores()">Somar</button>
</fieldset>
```

Veja, ao somar 10 + 10 + 10 temos o resultado como 30, que seria o correto.

Com base no seu código você poderia editar essa parte para um `parseInt()`.

```
calc_quant_total_produto += parseInt(quant_produto[i].value);
```

Além do `parseInt()` há também o `parseFloat()` para números que não são inteiros.

**Referências:**

- [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)
- [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

Comment: Aconselho a trocar as referências para a MDN que é mais confiável: [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) e [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).
Vale lembrar também que é importante passar o segundo parâmetro para o parseInt para evitar inconsistência de implementação dos navegadores.

Comment: Deu certo colocando o parseInt() ao somar o valor. Mas precisei também colocar um value padrão no html também pois acho que o somatório ficava nulo ao somar algum campo que ficava em branco. <input size="3" class="form-control" id="quant_produto" type="number"
                onchange="preencheTotalProduto()" min="1" max="<?= $tamanho['estoque'];?>" value="0">

Comment: @Bruno, você poderia fazer uma pequena validação antes com o JavaScript para ver se os campos foram realmente preenchidos. Além disso a questão do `value="0"` pode resolver, se os campos não são obrigatórios.

Comment: Mas alguns campos realmente não precisam ser preenchidos obrigatoriamente. Aqui pra mim a questão está resolvida. Mas não sei marcar o tópico como solucionado.

Comment: @Bruno, caso a resposta tenha resolvido o seu problema você pode marcar como aceita clicando no V verdinho do lado dos pontos da escolhida. Caso queira, pode dar um voto positivo também.

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado a todos pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Possivelmente os valores são do tipo '*text*', por isso a concatenação .

```
for(var i=0;i<tam_grade_produto.length;i++){
  var quantProduto = parseInt(quant_produto[i].value);
  calc_quant_total_produto+= quantProduto;
}
```

Caso queria converter para decimal, use: *parseFloat()*

Comment: Exato e vale lembrar @Bruno  que você está pegando selectorAll de "id" e id não se repete, em vez disso use class

Comment: Não entendi o que você disse sobre "id" não se repete. No trecho do código que mostrei está dentro de um loop que gera vários inputs com o mesmo id, então ele se repete sim, por isso o uso do selectorAll. Só não postei aqui o código html inteiro que foi gerado. E o uso do parseInt não deu certo. Ainda não consegui entender porque.

Comment: O id é usado para identificar apenas 1 elemento enquanto classe é para vários, de uma olhada http://tableless.github.io/iniciantes/manual/css/class-id.html ou pode consultar o próprio w3 @Bruno Pode funcionar aí, mas vai ter situações em que ele não funcionará, já passei por diversas, ele vai pegar sempre o ultimo elemento com o mesmo id, no seu caso ele pegou todos com aquele id e assim pega mesmo, mas caso você utilize o byId já daria confusão então comece a ver a diferença entre classe e id